# Creating PDF bookmarks when the highest level is below section

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I'm producing a small document where only unnumbered subsections and levels below are used, and would like `PDF` bookmarks to be created for them.

I tried [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [bookmark](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) packages and did not find any option for this. How do I make it automatically generate such bookmarks? What's the most elegant way of doing this?

Update: corrected inaccurate question statement. Sorry.

Comment: Why don't you use \section and change it so that is looks like you want it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Good call. Turns out I actually just need to use \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} to suppress numbering and preserve the toc and bookmark entries.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution (possible, since it is not quite clear what the problem might be)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\subsection{First}
\subsubsection{Below first}
\subsection{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image]