# Hypersetup environment warnings

Tags: hyperref, titles, warnings, subscripts

This is my title page of my thesis and the code is as below

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{
pdftitle={properties of F\textsubscript{2}},
pdfauthor={xxx},
pdfsubject={Masterthesis},
pdfkeywords={Master Thesis},
pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false} 
\end{document}
```

I get six warnings as below for using a subscript in this hypersetup environment. Is it the subscript causing the warning or something else? Could someone help me understand this better? Thank you.

> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string
> (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref)                removing '\mathsurround'
> on input line.
>
> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF
> string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref)                removing '\z@' on
> input line.
>
> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF
> string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref)                removing
> 'subscript' on input line.
>
> Package hyperref Info: Option
> 'pdfnewwindow' set 'true' on input line.
>
> Package hyperref Info: Option
> 'plainpages' set 'false' on input line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt your example compiles (no `\usepackage{hyperref}`).

Anyway, the following works without warnings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={\texorpdfstring{Properties of F\textsubscript{2}}{Properties of F2}},
  pdfauthor={xxx},
  pdfsubject={Masterthesis},
  pdfkeywords={Master Thesis},
  pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
  pdfnewwindow=true,
  pdfstartview=XYZ,
  plainpages=false}

\begin{document}
Blah.
\end{document}
```

Explanation: text strings for PDF metadata can't contain fancy TeX markup. [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s `\texorpdfstring` command allows one to specify two versions of a given string: the first argument may contain (La)TeX markup and is used for typesetting, whereas the second argument is used when the string is embedded as PDF metadata (title, author, subject, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @frougon. I have defined the package as \usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopenlevel=section,breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]{hyperref} . Is this correct way?

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted. Concerning what you ask, these are really different questions. `bookmarksopenlevel` should be an integer (see [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174794/creating-pdf-bookmarks-when-the-highest-level-is-below-section)). The rest seems okay at first sight (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175398/73317) for an authoritative post about `pdfborder`).

Comment: A year ago, `hyperref` didn't complain about a `\textsuperscript{o}` (although the metadata output was "3,52,5o" for it). I came back to the code today and I found not even `\texorpdfstring{\textsuperscript{o}}{º}` runs without errors :(, so I will have to accept a `\texorpdfstring{$^\text{o}$}{º}` (although the metadata will read "o" instead of "º").

Comment: @Andrestand Not sure if it is correct for the PDF metadata encoding, but `\texorpdfstring{Properties of F\textsubscript{o}}{Properties of Fº}` results in apparently correct metadata (displayed by `pdfinfo` and `okular`). Tested with TeX Live updated today, after seeing your comment.

Comment: Good point, I just checked pdf properties and mouse-hovering popup in Windows. That's how most people receiving my PDFs will have access to that info, on the other hand:(

Comment: @Andrestand By the way, unless you use something like `\edef\mypdftitle{\GetDocumentProperties{hyperref/pdftitle}}
\title{\mypdftitle}`, I don't think providing LaTeX markup for the `pdftitle` key is useful; do you have another use for it?

Comment: @frougon I'm not sure if I fully understand your comment, but I guess my answer is no. My point is that people using Windows will probably see `3o` instead of `3º` (which is how `3rd` is usually written in Spanish).

Comment: @Andrestand My comment was an interrogation regarding my own answer: I could have proposed `pdftitle={Properties of F2}`. I have the impression that using `\texorpdfstring` inside the `pdftitle` is likely not very useful as the value doesn't get typeset by LaTeX, unless one extracts it like I wrote using `\GetDocumentProperties`, then uses the result in typesetting. Now regarding your point: looking at §7.19, *Option ‘pdfencoding’* in the `hyperref` manual, Unicode seems to be supported by default nowadays for the information dictionary; so, AFAIUI, using `°` directly here should be fine.